# how to process large number files

Tags: c#, multithreading

I should process around 8000 files in directory and subdirectory. How can I process each files easily with thread/task and wait all?

For the moment, I use this code

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(@"E:\Nouveau dossier (2)",
                                                 "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var f in files)
{
    ToDo(f);
}
```

However it's very very slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep on mind that any correct answer has to deal with two things.

1. Reading files - this might not work well in parallel, especially on proper disks (not SSDs) because they have to position the head over each of the files and that cannot be done in parallel, obviously.
2. Processing files - once the data are in memory, you can process them on separate cores.

Now, which part of these two is taking more time? If it is reading files, and most often it will be the case, then there is no help from using multiple cores. They will still have to wait for the data to come in.

My advice to you is to make an experiment. Do not process the files, but only read them. Make your `ToDo()` function just read the file to the end. That is the minimum time you can get for your entire work.

Then try to read files in parallel, but be prepared to see that it takes more time than before... You can do that like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, ReadToEnd);
```

This assumes that `ReadToEnd()` is your test function which simply reads content of the file.

Comment: If the file processing is the time consuming part, the op shall not create more threads than the core count. When a thread ends with one (or n) files, it should get the next file data (or the next n files data) to process, locking the files data list during this operation.

Comment: That is true, but I don't expect to see the case in which processing takes more time than loading content. That is also why I suggested to measure performance without processing, only with loading, and see - if that is approximately the same as the time which includes processing, then there is no point in parallelizing anything as IO seems to be the bottleneck.

Comment: If it's one-way reading without building the DOM, then not. I made such routine a few weeks ago and it was incredibly fast. Depends on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try the Parallel.ForEach method. But it will not gurantee any peformance gain since the IO is the bootleneck.

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, (f) => {
    ToDo(f);
});
```

[system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Parallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

please find below an example:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(@"C:\Users\Myleo\Pictures", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var program = new Program();
    var result = program.ProcessInParallelWithCounter(files);
    Console.WriteLine("count: {0}", result);

    #if DEBUG
        Console.ReadKey();
    #endif
}

private void ProcessInParallel(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    // process
    Parallel.ForEach(files, Process);
}

private int ProcessInParallelWithCounter(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    // process and count
    var counter = 0;
    Parallel.ForEach(
        files,
        () => 0,
        (file, loopState, localCount) =>
                                        {
                                            Process(file);
                                            return ++localCount;
                                        },
        count => Interlocked.Add(ref counter, count));
    return counter;
}

private void Process(string file)
{
    // your code.
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just right off the bat, here are a few ways of using multiple threads to better utilize CPU power to speed up the processing, assuming that is where the bottleneck is. You may not get much of a performance improvement if the bottleneck is disk I/O, for example.

1. [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Task Parallel Library (TPL) ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [TaskFactory.StartNew Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Because reading files is IO operations then `async/await` approach seems best approach for this task.

You don't need waste threads for waiting while IO reading or writing to the files. Reading or writing to the files is operation which contains "waiting" for IO device's response. Creating separate thread which do nothing -> only waiting is wasting of resources and give no value for your application.

By using `async/await` you can do same job with only one thread. When first task waiting for file being read, another task will be started and so on.

You can make you `ToDo` method to works asynchronously

```
public async Task ToDoAsync(string file)
{
    using (var fileReader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        var allFile = await fileReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        // and do something
    }
}
```

And then use it

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(@"E:\Nouveau dossier (2)", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var f in files)
{
    var task = ToDoAsync(f);
    tasks.Add(task);
} 

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

So for better performance and better using of resources you need divide your logic in two parts, as metntioned in the @Zoran answer.

- Reading files which can be done in asynchronous way
- Processing data which can be done in "Parallel"

Answer (score 0):

You could run the `ToDo` in seperate Tasks

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(@"E:\Nouveau dossier (2)", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var f in files)
{
    var local = f;
    var tast = Task.Run(() => ToDo(local));

    tasks.Add(task);
}

Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try but can I execute 8000 tasks ? it's not dangerous ?

Comment: This won't create a thread for each operation, It will put them on the default TaskScheduler (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx)